# Setting visiblilty of control using LINQ

Tags: linq, collections, controls

I'm working on refactoring some code to practice LINQ. For some reason I can't get this code to cooperate.

```
        //ActionControls is a ControlCollection
var actionControls = flowLayoutPanel1.FilterControls(c => c is Button);

    //TODO: Optimize
  foreach(var control in actionControls)
  {
      control.Visible = workingItemDataTable.AsEnumerable().Any(row => "btn" + row.Field<string>("Name") == control.Name);
  }
```

What I am trying to do now.

```
flowLayoutPanel1.FilterControls(c => c is Button && c.Name == "btnTaskInfo"//btnTaskInfo is always visible
                   || workingItemDataTable.AsEnumerable().Any(row => "btn" + row.Field<string>("Name") == c.Name)).Cast<Button>()
```

But after casting this as a button, I can not figure out how to set visible = false. Any Advice?

Comment: linq is just syntactic sugar, you have to iterate on controls collection

Comment: i was hoping some kind of select statement or maybe a set or something. but thats what I thought I just wasnt sure

Answer (score 0):

You'd still need to iterate the controls, but you can probably do this, assuming FilterControls isn't much more than an alias for Where:

```
var actionControls = flowLayoutPanel1.OfType<Button>();
```

There are some "tricks" and shortcuts for iterating and doing sets within a lambda expression, but it makes the code just look messy and they are mostly just hacks.  You can create your own extension ForEach (if there isn't one available to you if you really want to do it anyway).

```
flowLayoutPanel1.OfType<Button>().ForEach(btn=>{btn.Visible= ... });
```

Comment: thats what I figured. and yeah filter controls does a little more, it filters from the top lvl parent all the way down the child line